# Get the real, apparent size of a folder

Tags: files, directory, disk-usage

I am using the `du` command in order to get the size of the folder. As I am interested in the actual size I ended up with the following command:

```
du –sh --apparent-size <someFolder>/
```

In this examples this returns `4.6M`. However I know that the folder actually has exactly 4M and WinSCP confirms it (4096KiB).

So what command would I have to use to get "4M" as a result (Preferrably in a human readable format)?

Also please be aware that I also need to include all subfolders so that it has to be recursive. Folder structure is something like this:

```
_cache
+-- _fold1
+-- _fold2
|   +-- _fold2.1
|       +-- file2.1.1
|       +-- file2.1....
|       +-- file2.1.5000
|   +-- _fold2.2
|       +-- file2.2.1
|       +-- file2.2....
|       +-- file2.2.5000
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `du -sk` or `du -sh` without the `--apparent-size` modifier.

Comment: without the modifier it returns a folder size of approx. `1G`. Although this might be the actual "size on disk" this is not the "real file size".

Comment: try running this command and see what it gives you `a=0;find some_dir_name_here -type f | xargs ls -l| while read line; do b=$(echo $line|awk '{print $5}'); (( a=$a+$b ));done; echo "Size is " $a`

Comment: Despite running very very long it always  returns 0. Maybe should have mentioned that the folder contains subfolders, so it has to be recursive.

Comment: find is recursive from the top level directory name you give, unless it is explicitly told the depth. Does this folder contain a lot of so-called sparse files by any chance ? Like database table containers and such ?

Comment: How many files are in that folder? Could your WinSCP be counting just the contents of the files and ignoring the actual folders?

Comment: @RealSkeptic 20 folders and around 10k files. The hierarchy is 3 levels deep.Updated the question to give you a rough example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `du` is intended to show disk usage. Disk usage for a directory includes the size the actual directory takes.

A directory is a special type of file that holds the names and inodes of all the files or other entries in it. This takes up disk space.

For example, I have created three directories.

One is `dir1`, which contains a single file sized 40M.
The directory `dir2` contains ten subdirectories, each of which contains a single file sized 4M.
The directory `dir3` contains ten thousand empty files.

Running `du -s -B 1 dir1 dir2 dir3` gives

```
41947136    dir1
41988096    dir2
258048  dir3
```

For small directories, a directory size (at least on an ext4 filesystem without any exotic settings) is 4096 bytes. For large directories (containing many files) the size is larger (as `ls -l` would tell you). Sum up the sizes of the directories together with the files, and I believe you will end up with the difference you are witnessing.

Comment: This was the missing part in my logic: `For large directories (containing many files) the size is larger`. When substracting the size of the folders itself I get the expected, exact 4096KiBs
Thank you

Comment: also if you filesystem has journalling the size can explode, if you want to see the real size of a dataset then du fails